# Swagger and .Net COre cannot find custom.css

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I've built an API project with .Net Core 3.0, adding Swagger 5.rc4 to show API documentation.

I want to customize CSS so I've added in the startup.Configure:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Geo API");
    c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
    c.DocumentTitle = "GeoData APIs";
    c.DisplayRequestDuration();
    c.EnableFilter();
    c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
});
```

I can see the swagger page at localhost:8888/docs/index.html but I'm not able to make it load the custom.css

In my project, I've created a folder "swagger-ui" containing the file custom.css, and set to be copied to the output directory. I can correctly see it, inside the swagger-ui folder, in the bin folder when I compile but no way to see it from the browser.

I've added also app.UseStaticFiles(); but nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you create the swagger-ui folder inside the wwwroot folder of your webapi?

Comment: @haldo yes it's there

Comment: Can you show us order of your Startup Configure methods? Is UseStaticFiles before routing and is UseSwaggerUI at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try steps below:

1. Create Asp.NET Core Web API 3.0
2. Edit the csproj to add reference below:

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
   ```
3. Add `swagger-ui` and `custom.css` to `wwwroot` with content below:

   ```
   body {
       background-color:yellow
   }
   ```
4. Change `Startup.cs`

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }

       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
           services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
           {
               c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
           });

       }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           }
           else
           {
               app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
               // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
               app.UseHsts();
           }
           app.UseHttpsRedirection();
           app.UseStaticFiles();

           app.UseRouting();

           app.UseAuthorization();
           app.UseSwagger();
           app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
           {
               c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Geo API");
               c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
               c.DocumentTitle = "GeoData APIs";
               c.DisplayRequestDuration();
               c.EnableFilter();
               c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
           });            

           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
           {
               endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: somehow this works from Visual Studio (2022), .net6.0 , but does not work with published files