# Swagger + .Net6 Web Api doesn't load custom.css

Tags: css, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Starting with this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239489/swagger-and-net-core-cannot-find-custom-css), I modified the `program.cs` file in my Web Api .Net6 project to include ...

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
   options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                                {
                                   Version = "v1",
                                   Title = "Blah.Api",
                                   Description = "Blah blah"
                                });
});
    
// ...

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
   options.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
   options.EnableFilter();
   options.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
});
```

I created a `wwwroot` folder with `swagger-ui` as a sub-folder and added a `custom.css` file to it with the following content...

```css
.swagger-ui .renderedMarkdown p {
    font-size: small;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

When I fired up my api, I noticed my custom css wasn't applied. A quick look with the dev tools in chrome showed me that the file was loading ok, but it was empty...

[image: Chrome DevTools Sources]

The css file is set as "Content", if that makes any difference.

There are no network errors reported and the Dev Tools Network tab reports a 200 for the custom.css file. It reports "16 B transferred over network, resource size 0 B" and it reports this regardless of how big the actual css file is.

I'm clearly not doing something I should be, but I can't see what that might be.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why it doesn't load

Have you add this in your Program.cs ?

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: I hadn't, no, but, sadly, adding it has made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I can display it according to your code.

1.Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -version 6.1.4

2.Configure the Swagger Middleware.

```
   using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {  Version = "v1" , Title = "Blah.Api", Description = "Blah blah" });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {  c.EnableFilter();
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "  V1 Blah.Api  Blah blah");
        c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
    });
}


app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

3.Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work for my webapi .NET 6.0 app:

1. Added folder wwwroot + custom.css in Visual Studio
2. Added config in Program.cs

   ```
   app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
   options.InjectStylesheet("/custom.css");
                      }
   app.UseStaticFiles();
   ```
3. Added css in custom.css

   ```
   body {
    }
    .swagger-ui .topbar {
        background-color: #ffd800;
        padding: 14px;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the file's **Copy to Output Directory** property solved the same issue for me. I set it to **Copy always** I hope it helps someone else :)